# Bootstrap popovers don't allow DOM access. What to do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have problems with Bootstrap (3.3.4) popovers. My html code for the popover is in the data-html tag, which also contains a class link_click. The jQuery click function for this class doesn't work. Why is jQuery not seeing  this link_click class from data-content field of the popover? What to change?

```
popover = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" data-content="<a href=\'javascript:void(0)\' class=\'link_click\'>Popover Link not working</a><br>">Main-Objekt</a>';

$('#popover_test').html( popover );

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ trigger:"manual", animation:false})
.on("mouseenter", function () {
var _this = this;
$(this).popover("show");
$(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
    $(_this).popover('hide');
});})
.on("mouseleave", function () {
var _this = this;
setTimeout(function () {
    if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
        $(_this).popover("hide");
    }
}, 100);
}); 

$('.link_click').click( function(){
    alert('Click success!');
});
```

Thanks

Michael

Comment: Bootstrap popovers allow DOM access just fine - It's your code that doesn't allow DOM access

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation for dynamic content:

```
$('#popover_test').on('click', '.link_click', function(){
    alert('Click success!');
});
```

Comment: Hi tymeJV, thank you very much, this took me hours, you saved my day. This works, Michael